# Max post size in WebLogic 12.2.1

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a probleme with WebLogic 12.2.1, after migrating from version 10.3.2 to version 12.2.1, I realized that I could have an authentication with a post larger than 4096 (it's a new constraint in WLO 12.1.2, reference: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLUPG/compat.htm#WLUPG473 )
the solution is to put an explicit value in the weblogic.xml, but this is not supported and i don't see any difference.

weblogic.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 8.1//EN" "weblogic810-web-jar.dtd">
<weblogic-web-app>
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>MYAPPAll</role-name>
        <principal-name>ENT_MYAPP_Users</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
    <reference-descriptor>
        <resource-description>
            <res-ref-name>DBAppDDXA</res-ref-name>
            <jndi-name>
                jdbc/DBAppDDXA
            </jndi-name>
        </resource-description>
        <resource-description>
            <res-ref-name>DBAppDD</res-ref-name>
            <jndi-name>
                jdbc/DBAppDD
            </jndi-name>
        </resource-description>
    </reference-descriptor>
    <session-descriptor>
        <session-param>
            <param-name>max-save-post-size</param-name>
            <param-value>10240</param-value>
        </session-param>    
        <session-param>
            <param-name>timeout-secs</param-name>
            <param-value>3600</param-value>
        </session-param>
    </session-descriptor>
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <jsp-param>
            <param-name>pageCheckSeconds</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </jsp-param>
        <jsp-param>
            <param-name>precompile</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </jsp-param>
        <jsp-param>
            <param-name>workingDir</param-name>
            <param-value>./jsp_precompile_dir/myAppVer2</param-value>
        </jsp-param>
        <jsp-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
        </jsp-param>
        <jsp-param>
          <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name> 
          <param-value>true</param-value>
         </jsp-param>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <container-descriptor>
        <servlet-reload-check-secs>-1</servlet-reload-check-secs>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>/myApp</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I get the same error:

> <26 janv. 2017 12 h 18 WET>   
>   <[ServletContext@227245410[app:src module:src path:null
>   spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an IOException.
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.MaxPostSizeExceededException:
>   MaxSavePostSize [4096] exceeded !     at
>   weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.raiseException(FormSecurityModule.java:564)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.stuffSession(FormSecurityModule.java:544)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.sendLoginPage(FormSecurityModule.java:494)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkUserPerm(FormSecurityModule.java:213)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.security.internal.FormSecurityModule.checkAccess(FormSecurityModule.java:96)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   >

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

`max-save-post-size` must not be defined as a `session-param` but the following way:

```
<session-descriptor>
    <max-save-post-size>10240</max-save-post-size>
</session-descriptor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i tried with that before max-save-post-size but nothing has changed, and there is a difference between the weblogic documentation, reference : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP587)

Comment: Glad this helped you!

Comment: What is the impact of increasing value of max-save-post-size. How would one decide the required value. In my case if the user is logged in and performs some work, and then the window is kept idle, the session times out. And then when he comes back and attempts to work on the form (which would generate a post request), it generates the mentioned error. The request size is not fixed since it depends on the number of lines that are populated into the form before the session expired.