# Unable to upload 100MB file using ServletFileUpload

Tags: java, spring

I have to upload the 100MB file. My front end part is Angular 4 and backend part is in Java and Spring 4 . I have exposed it as REST endpoint. Once i upload the file after sometime the connection get break and it does not return anything to the front end.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertDoc.action", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> insertDoc(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(name = "docType", required = false) final String docType) {
        List<DocumentMetadataVO> docIdList = new ArrayList<DocumentMetadataVO>();
        try {

            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(request));

            if (isMultipart) {
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
                upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

                List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                for (FileItem fileItem : items) {
                    DocumentMetadataVO documentMetadataVO = new DocumentMetadataVO();
                    documentMetadataVO.setFileData(fileItem.get());
                    documentMetadataVO.setDocumentName(fileItem.getName());
                    documentMetadataVO.setUploadDate(new Date());
                    logger.info("File Name is::" + documentMetadataVO.getDocumentName());
                    documentMetadataVO.setDocType(docType);
                    String docId = commonService.insertDocument(request, documentMetadataVO);
                    documentMetadataVO.setDocId(docId);
                    docIdList.add(documentMetadataVO);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(getModelMapError(e.getMessage()),
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(getMap(docIdList), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Large file uploaded fail with no stacktrace in Spring App is an indicator of wrong Tomcat configuration.

Tomcat automatically drop connection if your file is too large (eventhough you set your `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.http.multipart.max-request-size` properties).

So to solve it, you should config tomcat to allow large file upload

Open `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` and edit the following properties:

```
<!-- 150MB max -->
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>157286400</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>209715200</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: What if i deploy my war on Weblogic ?

Comment: I have no exp with WebLogic. But [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873417/max-post-size-in-weblogic-12-2-1)

Comment: I did as you mentioned but it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

the multipart resolver size can also be specified in your application xml file. You can either do it via that or via programitcally

**Application xml**

To add it to your xml file you can add a bean like thus:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="16777215" />
</bean>
```

**Programatically**

To add it programatically and possibly configurable try this:

```
/**
 * Configuration to set the multipart Resolver bean and the max upload size
 *
 */
@Configuration
@Component
public class MultipartResolverBeanConfig {


  /**
   * Create the multipart resolver bean
   * Set the maximum upload file size 
   * @return
   */
  @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(157286400L);
    return multipartResolver;
  }
}
```

Comment: If i do this multipart process the request before it reaches to controller

Comment: This will configure your multipart process and you do not have to do anything else.