# Web Logic - Managed Server - MaxPostSizeExceededException

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

On the managed server log I can see the following exception.

weblogic.servlet.internal.MaxPostSizeExceededException: MaxSavePostSize [4096] exceeded

Reading through I have found the following oracle explanation.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLUPG/compat.htm#WLUPG473

The question I have are

1. How can I set this value? Is it possible to define it in the weblogic console, against managed server node?
2. How can I figure out the value required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was on MaxSavedPostSize. Update the weblogic.xml files for the application in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the WebLogic console.

Under Environment->Servers, go into you managed server, then go to the Protocols tab, and within that the HTTP tab.

The third setting in that section is "Max Post Size".

The help for that says:

> The maximum post size this server allows for reading HTTP POST data in a servlet request.
>   A value less than 0 indicates an unlimited size.

The maximum size you need depends on what your application is doing and what data you'll be sending back from the web client. You can increase it incrementally until the errors stop, or try to work out the maximum amount of data that could possibly be set.

Or you can set it to, say, -1 to avoid the issue entirely. You could end with a huge amount of data being posted though, so be a bit careful about doing that.

Comment: Thanks Alex. We set the value to -1 as mentioned. However, ./we still see the same error on the managed server logs.

Comment: @user3505441 Not sure if you're still out there. I have also seen this problem and our `MaxPostSize` is already set to -1 (unlimited). It seems `MaxPostSize` and `MaxSavePostSize` are different parameters. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41873961/1461424

Comment: Hi Alex, My Question was not on Max Post Size. It was on MaxSavedPostSize. Can see that I should update the weblogic.xml files for the application in question.